# Qnap Container: Gitlab-runner cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, qnap

Currently a gitlab docker is running on my qnap. I would also like to create a gitlab-runner on the qnap container station for the CI pipeline. I have registered the gitlab runner and it can also be seen under the gitlab ui.

But when i run a CI-Pipeline in gitlab, i get this error:

`Running with gitlab-runner 15.10.0 (456e3482)   on Runner for local gitlab bcoxG6HN, system ID: r_hsMqK7G0hio2 Preparing the "docker" executor 00:09 ERROR: Failed to remove network for build ERROR: Preparation failed: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:754:0s) Will be retried in 3s ... ERROR: Failed to remove network for build ERROR: Preparation failed: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:754:0s) Will be retried in 3s ... ERROR: Failed to remove network for build ERROR: Preparation failed: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:754:0s) Will be retried in 3s ... ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:754:0s)`

I have also defined a shared folder in the gitlab-runner:

`/var/run/docker.sock /share/GitLabRunner/var/run/docker.sock`

What I am doing wrong?
Whats the right way to get it to run on a qnap nas?